# rails kaminari pagination inappropriate link when using ransack search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

here is my route.rb:

```
match "search" => "welcome#search" , via: [:get, :post]
```

and here is my search method in welcome controller:

```
def search
    @search = Poem.search(params[:q])
    @poems = @search.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page]).per(15)
  end
```

and here is my search view:

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: search_path , html: { method: :post }  do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :content_cont %>
  <%= f.text_field :content_cont %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => 'show' %>
```

and here is my show partial :

```
<%= paginate @poems%>
.... ( other stuff)
```

I'm using ransack to perform advanced search it does work but pagination links are like this:

```
http://0.0.0.0:8080/search?authenticity_token=oiOmBeY80DH0zAN5lST%2BCo355phcr3TGqOSlTQ1qtlc%3D&commit=Search&page=2&q%5Bcontent_cont%5D=&utf8=%E2%9C%93
```

kind of post/get problem.

any suggestion?

Comment: Have you seen this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115690/is-there-any-possible-way-to-fix-the-url-that-kaminari-pagination-generates

Comment: that makes the code dirty. that is not the best solution. but tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is like 2 years late, but this other solution works for me and I'm just cross posting it here:

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/182#issuecomment-122124373

> I've found a way to just basically do a post appending the value of the pagination link as an input field to the form, that way you can avoid having the url params in your address bar and also potentially prevent an HTTP 414 error.

```
$(function() {
  $('.pagination a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    $('form').append("<input type='text' name='page' value=" + e.target().text() + "/>");
    $('form').submit();
  });
});
```

> Please let me know if this solves your issue or it's not what you're looking for!
>
> Hope it helps, have fun!