# Ajax pagination with Kaminari works, but how to update page_entries_info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, view, kaminari

I am new to Ruby on Rails and after an intensive search to find an  answer here, I decided to post my question:

I have implemented Ajax pagination with Kaminari according to the awesome git log example from Akira Matsuda [here](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari_example/commits/ajax).

The pagination itself works great, but the 'page_entries_info' that shows which entries are being listed, i.e. "Displaying favorites 11 - 20 of 34 in total" does not update. It stays with the initial value "Displaying favorites 1 - 10 of 34 in total".

I have added the ":remote => true" option, without success. My code looks like this:

index.html.erb

```
<h1>All Favorites</h1>

<div id="paginator" class="pagination_div center">
  <%= paginate @favorites, :remote => true %>
</div>

<div class="pagination_count pull-left">
  <%= page_entries_info @favorites, :remote => true %>
</div>

<table class="search_results table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>User Id</th>
      <th>User email</th>
      <th>Lesson Id</th>
      <th>Lesson name</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="favorites">
    <%= render 'favorite' %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I render a partial "_favorite.html.erb":

```
<% @favorites.each do |favorite| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= favorite.id %></td>
    <td><%= favorite.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= favorite.user.email %></td>
    <td><%= favorite.lesson_id %></td>
    <td><%= favorite.lesson.name %></td>
    <td><img class="delete_favorite" src="<%=asset_path('trash.png')%>" lid="<%= favorite.lesson_id %>"></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Here is my index.js.erb:

```
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@favorites, :remote => true).to_s) %>'); 
$('#favorites').html('<%= escape_javascript render('favorite') %>');
```

favorites_controller.rb

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_action :verify_if_logged_in

  def index
    @favorites = Favorite.all.page(params[:page])
  end
...
end
```

favorite.rb

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :lesson
end
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you post, some more code controller where you are defining `@favorites` and where you have defined `favorites` div

Comment: hi Sontya, I added more code. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by adding the following code in index.js.erb:

```
 $('#counter').html('<%= escape_javascript(page_entries_info(@favorites, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

and adding id="counter" to the div in index.html.erb:

```
<div id="counter"class="pagination_count pull-left">
  <%= page_entries_info @favorites, :remote => true %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this

Index.erb

```
<tbody id="favorites">
    <%= render @favorites %>
</tbody>
```

index.js.erb

```
$('tbody#favorites').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@favorites) %>');

$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@favorites, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

Comment: Thanks Sontya, I tried your code but it is still not updating, instead I see 100 favorites on the first page now (looks like the favorites are being displayed repetitively 10 times )..

Comment: call your partial like this only `<%= render 'favorite' %>`

Comment: try this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115690/is-there-any-possible-way-to-fix-the-url-that-kaminari-pagination-generates

Comment: Thanks again. But in the meantime I found a solution. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kaminari uses Active Record's offset method to create the `page_entries_info` text. Just adding an order scope to your query should fix this.

```
  class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :lesson
    default_scope ->{ order('id) }
  end
```